# How to get the key of a hash

Tags: ruby

Right now I have a double hash called data like the following:

```
data [name][action]
```

ie

```
 data = {"Mike" => {"Walked" => 13, "Ran" => 5}, "Steve" => {...}}
```

For this particular hash, I don't actually know the keys in the hash, I just want to iterate over it, like so:

```
data.each |item| do
    #how to get the key name for item here?
    puts item["Walked"].to_s
    puts item["Ran"].to_s
end
```

I'd like to get the key so I can display it in a table beside the values.

Comment: [Hash#each_pair {| key, value | block }](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-each_pair)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use each with a key, value syntax, as described in the [`each` documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-each):

```
data.each do |key, values|
  puts key.to_s
  values.each do |value|
    value.to_s
  end
end
```

You could also use `keys` or `values` depending on what you wanted to achieve.

```
data.keys.each do |key|
  puts key #lists all keys
end

data.values.each do |value|
  puts value #lists all values
end

data.keys.first #first key
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over a hash using:

```
data.each do |key, value|

end
```